# Can not run another application service with intent

Tags: android, android-service

I have two application (A and B).
I have a service in app B and Want to run it from app A.

I tried to do that like below code:

```
try {
   String packageName = "codenevisha.com.apps.learningmanagementsystem";
   String appService = "codenevisha.com.apps.learningmanagementsystem.activity.InternetService";
   Log.i("LOGO_UPDATE", appService + "\n");

   Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, appService));
   main.this.startService(i);

  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

And this is manifest in app B:

```
<service
   android:name=".activity.InternetService"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
 </service>
```

But it doesn't work with no error.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `startService(new Intent(this, appService));`

Comment: @pskink I didn't get your point but I want to run service app B from app A  as I explained but it doesn't work and I don't get any error.

Comment: @Nilu Thanks, but it didn't work for me

Comment: @pskink i get nothing in logcat

Comment: @pskink  the result is:   Starting service: Intent { cmp=codenevisha.com.apps.learningmanagementsystem/.activity.InternetService }

Comment: @pskink what i have to Log.d("TAG" , ?);